# My website shows hostname url instead of domain name url

Tags: url, redirect, dns, openshift

i have hosted my website in `openshift` cloud platform and i have got my domain from godaddy domain seller, after i have hosted my application, my domain name redirects to my hosting url

let us say i have domain name as

```
www.yellowbox.com
```

and i have my cloud hosted url as

```
  yellowbox-boxsoft.rhcloud.com
```

`godaddy.com` redirects to my cloud host when i hit www.yellowbox.com , but i see problems where i have href links which show my cloud url

```
  yellowbox-boxsoft.rhcloud.com/addUser.html
```

and this really bothers me, i would like to have my domain url instead of hosting url as below

```
www.yellowbox.com/addUser.html
```

i am new to cloud hosting and domain related topic, need some direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things that could be going on:

1.)  You could be using domain masking at godaddy and not have things setup correctly for openshift.  Basically it is loading your open shift gear in a somewhat of an iframe on the page, so as far as your open shift page is concerned, it is still being visited at your app-domain.rhcloud.com address

2.)  you are generating your links as FQDN links instead of relative links, and using your application url in them.  use relative links instead (like /addUser.html)

You should be setting up your www.example.com as a cname record that points to your app-domain.rhcloud.com address, and then things should work just fine.

Comment: i have added cname entry in godaddy site, and it does work, but i am facing problem in domain forwarding now, i have my domain forwarding ur1 as yellowbox-boxsoft.rhcloud.com/app-context<yellowbox>/ , now the domain forwarding stopped working after adding cname, all i have to do is www.yellowbox.com/yellowbox.. but this is weird for me..

Comment: If this is a java application, all you need to do is rename your war file to ROOT.war and it will be displayed at www.yellowbox.com

Comment: but is there any other way so that i can survive with context instead of ROOT, since i am planing to convert my war to ear in future..